# Как добавить #define в .sln-файл?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я знаю, что можно задать #define-константы в .csproj,
я знаю, что можно передать их через параметр командной строки msbuild.
Хочется прописать эти константы в .sln-файл, чтобы во-первых они были записаны (заскриптованы), а во-вторых действовали сразу на все проекты в solution.

Можно, конечно, написать внешний .proj-файл, который будет вызывать msbuild и передавать ему нужные константы, а уже msbuild будет внутри собирать .sln, но если есть возможность просто использовать .sln - хотелось бы в первую очередь понять как использовать именно эту возможность (обойтись минимальным количеством файлов и сохранить верность принципам DRY и "что не заскриптовано того не существует")

UPD:
Есть же интерфейс IVsPersistSolutionProps - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionprops.aspx
в нём есть методы SaveSolutionProps и WriteSolutionProps, значит наверное всё-таки свойства можно сохранять в .sln ?

А ещё бывает секция (только она про другое - показывать или нет корневой узел в окне solution explorer)

```
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, с SLN вам это не удастся. SLN — это простой список проектов без какой-либо дополнительной семантики (ну, кроме группировки и таргетов). Попробуйте по-другому: сделайте включение общих настроек на уровне csproj, поместите их в общий файл, и подключайте руками в каждый csproj.

Comment: тогда внешний .proj выглядит привлекательнее, потому что он один, а не "менять каждый .csproj" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5120423/1709408

Comment: О, файл «сбоку» — это ещё более чистое решение.

Comment: @VladD Что-то я не уловил, насколько решение "сбоку" сочетается со сборкой солюшена по F6, например.

Comment: Солшен в monodevelop собирается по F8. Решение сбоку позволяет автоматизировать сборку в некоторых use-case (например сборку пакетов для linux). Решение не обязано быть универсальным. Решение обязано быть работающим.

Comment: @Discord: Со сборкой оригинала — никак. Но можно создать альтернативный .sln, включающий «боковой» проект.

Comment: @VladD Это ж неудобно. Собственно, тогда надо исходить из того, что нужно. Если сборка солюшена в IDE и общие настройки — файл с настройками и инклюды в проектах. Если сборка в CI или где-то ещё отдельно — отдельный скрипт MSBuild.

Comment: Окей. Вы уговорили меня на инклюды в проектах. Но я не понимаю, как их написать, задал новый вопрос на английском SO, он в комментарии к ответу Discord.

Comment: @Discord: Угу, как-то так. Жаль, что нет универсально-хорошего решения. Для своего кода я бы не поленился и вытащил общие настройки проектов в отдельный импортируемый файл (VS по идее такие вещи не понимает и не трогает).

Comment: @hse5yzdx В большинстве виденных мной опен-сорсных проектов с поддержкой разных версий фреймворка зоопарк проектов... Нормальное решение вообще существует?

Comment: "решение вообще существует?", - я первый спросил! :)

Answer (score 4):

Если хочется иметь общие настройки для нескольких проектов, то традиционно создаётся общий скрипт MSBuild, который содержит нужные вам настройки, а в файлах проектов он включается через `<Import Project="">`. Учитывая, что Visual Studio вечно превращает содержимое файлов проектов в кашу, не вижу большого смысла следить за стерильностью их содержимого.

В сам файл .SLN подобные настройки вы не положите, потому что он на это не расчитан, он вообще оторван от проектных систем.

Comment: репозиторий не мой и у меня не примут PR, в котором необоснованно перекорячены 25 .csproj-файлов. А один дополнительный .proj, который никому не мешает, примут.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562881/how-to-set-define-in-msbuild-script-for-linux